# how to display the ouput of table to XML function in PSQL using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, postgresql, object

I am trying to display the output of:

```
select * from table_to_xml('"person_data1"',false,true,'');
```

in a JSP page. I got the output in a terminal as well as in pgadmin3.

I have created a Java function to execute above query and that function will return resultset in to the JSP page.

```
ResultSet rs1=common2.tabletoxml("person_data1");
while (rs1.next())
           {   
            out.print(rs1.getString(1));// when i tried this i got all data but not in xml form so I tried this 
            out.print(rs1.getSQLXML(1));//got object name
            }
```

What should I do to get XML values in JSP page? I have tried `valueOf()` but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to cast the result of the function to text, and maybe simplifying the query a bit while you're at it:

```
select table_to_xml('"person_data1"',false,true,'')::text;
```

You should then be able to read it with `getString(1)`.